# Rails 4: Adding or linking an attribute to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a `Applicant` with `name`, `email`, `grade`, and `major` attributes. What is going to happen is that applicants are going to show up to an event and "sign up" by submitting a form that corresponds to the `new/create` actions of the `Applicant` controller. The thing is, a few days after this initial sign up, the applicants will navigate to the website and submit a PDF (probably through Paperclip), that represents their application documents. This submission will always occur after the initial signup, but I want a way to access this PDF as an attribute of the `Applicant` controller, and I preferably don't want to have applicants set up a password (I don't want them to have to sign in and stuff like this.)

Is there any way to achieve this functionality? Maybe with another controller/model, and with foreign keys? There will never be more than >150 applicants in the database at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model called Document. This way you can even set up a nested_form and using fields_for you can upload multiple documents for one application if required in future.

Something like below,

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :path,:applicant_id

  belongs_to :applicant 

  mount_uploader :path, DocumentUploader # carrierwave that manages upload of docs
end
```

Comment: So when someone goes on the site and uploads the document, how does the backend link the document to the corresponding `Applicant` object? Remember, I don't want the applicant to have to sign in, I just want there to be a public form on some page of the site where he/she can input his/her information and the attachment. Sorry, I'm pretty new to Rails, so I'm not quite understanding how this connects on the backend.

Comment: Backend link the document to an applicant object by the help of applicant_id.

Comment: How does that work though? The applicant then has to input this `applicant_id`, right?